# Why is my flask app returning empty pages

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Python web frameworks and trying to learn Flask.  I went through the tutorial and all was good.  I am now trying to make my own little app to learn the framework.  I had in my main flask.py file the following code

```
@app.route('/') 
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

In main.html I have this html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div> Foo bar test</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and then in layout.html I have a basic web layout that looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>       
<title>Flaskpad</title>     
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<link href="/static/css/flaskpad.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">  
.socials {   
padding: 10px;   
}   
</style>  

</head>  
<body>  
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">  
        <div class="navbar-inner">  
                <div class="container">  
                    <ul class="nav">  
                    <li class="active">  
                            <a class="brand" href="#">Flaskpad/a>  
                    </li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row fcontent">
            <div class="span3">
                Empty Space
            </div>
            <div class="span6 maincontent">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                Empty Space
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ffooter">
            <div class="span12">
                Made by Bar Foo
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

I know the css links are done incorrectly but I just have them there as placeholders.  Now when I run python flask.py and go to localhost:5000 the page turns up blank and I cannot figure out why.  If I put in normal text in the main.html before the extends that will show up so I know it is loading main.html but it seems to not be extending the layout.  The page literally is blank as when you view source there is nothing.  I cannot figure this out.

Comment: just in case try to run your app in debug mode, maybe (maybe) it will print out something useful. app.run(debug=True). Also I would suggest just try render layout.html itself first and see if Flask grabs it at all. If it does then something wrong with inheritance...

Comment: The fact that when you add text outside of the `content` block in main.html it shows up indicates that Jinja2 is unable to find your layout.html file (the extend command is failing - otherwise text outside the blocks would not be rendered).  Can you post the entirety of your `.py` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on it, I couldn't get it to work.  I made a new directory, copied and pasted the text into new files and then ran it and it worked successfully.

I do not know why this was not working in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me. Do you have your HTML files in a folder named "templates" relative to your python module?

Here's my full test code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Edit**: You said: "I had in my main flask.py file the following code" - You should probably not name it flask.py, this may be screwing things up.

Comment: Thank but these didn't solve the issues.  My layout.html and my main.html are both in /templates and I've confirmed they are spelled correctly.  I've also renamed the flask.py to something else to see and that did not do anything either.

Comment: Versions? I have Flask==0.9, Jinja2==2.6, Werkzeug==0.8.3

Comment: All the newest versions for me.  I just installed them.

Comment: Well I don't know what else to say. It works for me using your templates.

Comment: Python version? I'm using 2.7.3

Comment: python 2.7.x I can't remember which subversion

Comment: Are you sure you have Jinja2 and not the original Jinja? Easy mistake to make if you're using pip to do your installs.

Comment: But why would the templates work in the tutorial that works but not in my own app?  I am doing similar actions so I don't think it is this issue but I am going to try tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Which web browser are you using for your testing?

I tried your code and it worked for me using chrome and firefox but I did notice that you have an incorrectly closed anchor tag in your `layout.html` at the line

```
<a class="brand" href="#">Flaskpad/a>
```

Maybe that is causing the browser to show the page as blank?

Comment: I didn't realize that so thanks.  I made the change but it didnt seem to affect the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the opening `<head>` tag in the layout.html ? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Yeah but that is not affecting it.